# Facing issue in getting token in ios

Tags: ios, token

I am facing problem in getting the token when I am running the app in my PC. It is working fine when I am running my app on MacBook.

This is the error:

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
"Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Length" = 37;
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Mon, 11 Jul 2016 09:27:28 GMT";
"QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1";
Server = "nginx/1.8.1";
Status = "422 Unprocessable Entity";
"X-Rack-Cache" = "invalidate, pass";
"X-Request-Id" = 7d09604a50a13d47b67c9b72e00d765f;
"X-Runtime" = "0.016969";
"X-UA-Compatible" = "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
```

Comment: that isn't an error. show us the request content, the expected request content and the response text

Comment: iOS app dont work on PC ( non mac OS ) systems.

Comment: ok @Hasya. Thank You for your exact answer. Can you tell me the reason as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS app dont work on PC ( non mac OS ) systems.

So when you try to open/run an app ( ipa file ) on non mac systems it will not function same as mac system.

Windows system install and run .exe files, while mac systems works with .ipa or .dmg files.

Even it will not work on linux based systems.